# My animation is very laggy and i cant find the way how to correct it. Any method or tips?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a page-turning book but the animation is very choppy and can even freeze in places. I'm trying to improve the JS in every possible way so that the whole page doesn't freeze.

I think the error is in `updatePageContent()` because it updates the pages and when I scroll it is brutally jagged and doesn't even load properly.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const book = document.getElementById('book');
  let currentLocation = 1;
  const numOfPapers = 1000;
  let maxLocation = numOfPapers + 1;
  const nextBtn = document.createElement('button');
  nextBtn.id = 'next-btn';
  nextBtn.textContent = 'Next';
  const prevBtn = document.createElement('button');
  prevBtn.id = 'prev-btn';
  prevBtn.textContent = 'Previous';


  nextBtn.style.position = 'absolute';
  nextBtn.style.right = '20px';
  nextBtn.style.bottom = '20px';
  prevBtn.style.position = 'absolute';
  prevBtn.style.left = '20px';
  prevBtn.style.bottom = '20px';

  document.body.appendChild(prevBtn);
  document.body.appendChild(nextBtn);

  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', goNextPage);
  prevBtn.addEventListener('click', goPrevPage);

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfPapers; i++) {
    const paper = document.createElement('div');
    paper.className = 'paper';
    paper.id = `p${i + 1}`;

    const front = document.createElement('div');
    front.className = 'front';
    const frontContent = document.createElement('div');
    frontContent.className = 'front-content';
    frontContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Front ${i + 1}</h1>`;
    front.appendChild(frontContent);

    const back = document.createElement('div');
    back.className = 'back';
    const backContent = document.createElement('div');
    backContent.className = 'back-content';
    backContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Back ${i + 1}</h1>`;
    back.appendChild(backContent);

    paper.appendChild(front);
    paper.appendChild(back);

    book.appendChild(paper);

  }

  function updatePageContent() {
    if (currentLocation > 1) {
      const prevPage = document.getElementById(`p${currentLocation - 1}`);
      const prevFrontContent = prevPage.querySelector('.front-content');
      const prevBackContent = prevPage.querySelector('.back-content');
      prevFrontContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Front ${currentLocation * 2 - 2}</h1>`;
      prevBackContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Back ${currentLocation * 2 - 1}</h1>`;
    }

    if (currentLocation <= numOfPapers) {
      const currentPage = document.getElementById(`p${currentLocation}`);
      const currentFrontContent = currentPage.querySelector('.front-content');
      const currentBackContent = currentPage.querySelector('.back-content');
      currentFrontContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Front ${currentLocation * 2}</h1>`;
      currentBackContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Back ${currentLocation * 2 + 1}</h1>`;
    }

    if (currentLocation < numOfPapers) {
      const nextPage = document.getElementById(`p${currentLocation + 1}`);
      if (nextPage) {
        const nextFrontContent = nextPage.querySelector('.front-content');
        const nextBackContent = nextPage.querySelector('.back-content');
        nextFrontContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Front ${currentLocation * 2 + 1}</h1>`;
        nextBackContent.innerHTML = `<h1>Back ${currentLocation * 2 + 2}</h1>`;
      }
    }
  }



  function openBook() {
    book.style.transform = "translateX(50%)";
  }

  function closeBook(isAtEnd) {
    if (isAtEnd) {
      book.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    } else {
      book.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    }
  }

  function goNextPage() {
    if (currentLocation < maxLocation) {
      currentLocation++;
      const currentPage = document.getElementById(`p${currentLocation}`);
      currentPage.classList.add("flipped");
      currentPage.style.zIndex = currentLocation;

      if (currentLocation === 1) {
        openBook();
      } else if (currentLocation === numOfPapers) {
        closeBook(false);
      }

      updatePageContent();
    }
  }

  function goPrevPage() {
    if (currentLocation > 1) {
      const currentPage = document.getElementById(`p${currentLocation}`);
      currentPage.classList.remove("flipped");
      currentPage.style.zIndex = numOfPapers - currentLocation + 1;

      currentLocation--;

      if (currentLocation === 1) {
        closeBook(true);
      } else if (currentLocation < numOfPapers) {
        openBook();
      }

      updatePageContent();
    }
  }


  document.getElementById('next-btn').addEventListener('click', goNextPage);
  document.getElementById('prev-btn').addEventListener('click', goPrevPage);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: powderblue;
}


/* Book */

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}

.back {
  z-index: 0;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}


/* Paper flip effect */

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* Controller Buttons */

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover i {
  color: #636363;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/* Paper stack order */

#p1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#p2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#p3 {
  z-index: 1;
}

`* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: powderblue;
}


/* Book */

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}

.back {
  z-index: 0;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}


/* Paper flip effect */

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* Controller Buttons */

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover i {
  color: #636363;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/* Paper stack order */

#p1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#p2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#p3 {
  z-index: 1;
}

`* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: powderblue;
}


/* Book */

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}

.back {
  z-index: 0;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}


/* Paper flip effect */

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* Controller Buttons */

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover i {
  color: #636363;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/* Paper stack order */

#p1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#p2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#p3 {
  z-index: 1;
}

`* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: powderblue;
}


/* Book */

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}

.back {
  z-index: 0;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}


/* Paper flip effect */

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* Controller Buttons */

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover i {
  color: #636363;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/* Paper stack order */

#p1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#p2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#p3 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="book" class="book">
  <div id="p1" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f1" class="front-content">
        <h1>Front 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div id="b1" class="back-content">
        <h1>Back 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made an executable snippet from the code you added to the question, but I would assume at least the CSS is missing. Can you please edit the question to include all relevant code to recreate the issue

Comment: With a small number of pages (eg 10) I see no lagging. With 1000 pages the system cannot run it at all, but I assume that’s because I’m currently on a smaller device (iPad)

Comment: Yeah its okey but if i click on the prev page button the animation its still laggy and cant load the page h1 tags its still on H1 front1 tag. And the button its cant see...